# Printing messages on the OSGi console

Tags: console, osgi, printf, declarative-services

I'm implementing a very light weight (embedded) OSGi framework which runs on a target piece of hardware. To attach a console I'm using org.apache.felix.gogo.shell and org.apache.felix.shell.remote.

To date, I've logged all custom messages using System.out.println which has worked fine, but now that I'm using the remote console I require something that will allow me to 'print' my messages to the OSGi console (and hopefully appear both on the target's console as well as the telnet console provided by felix.shell.remote).

I'm guessing there must be a way to get a handle to an OutputStream (or similar) to do this; My question is how? It seems that most people redirect their stdout etc. to solve problems like this.

I'm using declarative services, so I was hoping to be able to setup a component which attaches a referenced service (not important, but would make it nice and neat).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use logging for custom messages using the OSGi Log Service. That way you can get recent logs from the LogReader service from inside your shell or webconsole. If you insist on using popular frameworks like log4j etc. then you can get a bridge with Pax logging.

Alternatively, redirecting the output to a file in a known location works. You can then make a command in gogo that views that file or provide a tail function that continuously displays the new parts of the file.

Comment: I've already got a very specific logging implementation (to database; I've got very tight disk space requirements), so I'm really hesitant to touch the OSGi Log Service (unless you can turn off writing to disk?).

I'm really after a service exposed by the shell runtime that gives me an output stream, or output streams for each attached console.

I thought I could use a CommandProvider and save the CommandInterpreter(ci) object, then use ci.print() for each log message, however it looks like the ci object gets destroyed after that method has finished (redirects to the main console instead).

Comment: The OSGi log service is ONLY an intermediary. It keeps a short buffer to have history during startup. So it is very little work to catch the log records and write them to disk. See the OSGi Log Reader service.